# How to find prev/next document after sort in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongo-java-driver

I want to find `prev/next` blog documents whose publish date is closest to the input document.

Below is the document structure.

**Collection Examples (blog)**

```
{
    blogCode: "B0001",
    publishDate: "2020-09-21"
},
{
    blogCode: "B0002",
    publishDate: "2020-09-22"
},
{
    blogCode: "B0003",
    publishDate: "2020-09-13"
},
{
    blogCode: "B0004",
    publishDate: "2020-09-24"
},
{
    blogCode: "B0005",
    publishDate: "2020-09-05"
}
```

If the input is `blogCode = B0003`

**Expected output**

```
{
    blogCode: "B0005",
    publishDate: "2020-09-05"
},
{
    blogCode: "B0001",
    publishDate: "2020-09-21"
}
```

How could I get the output result? In sql, it seems using `ROW_NUMBER` can solve my problem, however I can't find a solution to achieve the feature in MongoDB. The alternate solution may be reference to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42093905/10090927) (But, it seems inefficient). Maybe using [mapReduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/map-reduce/) is another better solutions? I'm confused at the moment, please give me some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go like following.

1. We need to compare existing date with given date. So I used `$facet` to categorize both dates
2. The original data should be one Eg : B0003. So that I just get the first element of the `origin[]` array to compare with `rest[]` array
3. used `$unwind` to flat the `rest[]`
4. Substract to get the different between both dates
5. Again used `$facet` to find previous and next dates.
6. Then combined both to get your expected result

**NOTE** : The final array may have `0<elements<=2`. The expected result given by you will not find out whether its a prev or next date if there is a one element. So my suggestion is add another field to say which date it is as the mongo playground shows

```
[{
    $facet: {
        origin: [{
            $match: { blogCode: 'B0001' }
        }],
        rest: [{
            $match: {
                $expr: {
                    $ne: ['$blogCode','B0001']
                }
            }
        }]
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        origin: {
            $arrayElemAt: ['$origin',0]
        },
        rest: 1
    }
}, {
    $unwind: {path: '$rest'}
}, {
    $project: {
        diff: {
            $subtract: [{ $toDate: '$rest.publishDate' },{ $toDate: '$origin.publishDate'}]
        },
        rest: 1,
        origin: 1
    }
}, {
    $facet: {
        prev: [{
                $sort: {diff: -1}
            },
            {
                $match: {
                    diff: {$lt: 0 }
                }
            },
            {
                $limit: 1
            },
            {
                $addFields:{"rest.type":"PREV"}
            }
        ],
        next: [{
                $sort: { diff: 1 }
            },
            {
                $match: {
                    diff: { $gt: 0 }
                }
            },
            {
                $limit: 1
            },
            {
                $addFields:{"rest.type":"NEXT"}
            }
        ]
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        combined: {
            $concatArrays: ["$prev", "$next"]
        }
    }
}, {
    $unwind: {
        path: "$combined"
    }
}, {
    $replaceRoot: {
        newRoot: "$combined.rest"
    }
}]
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ePJI6SMo40N)**

Comment: Thanks for your explanation so clearly. It solve my problems well. I also find another method which by applying [includeArrayIndex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#includearrayindex)

Answer (score 1):

Inspire for the solution of `varman` proposed. I also find another way to solve my problem by using [includeArrayIndex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#includearrayindex).

```
[
  {
    $sort: {
      "publishDate": 1
    },
    
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: 1,
      root: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    },
    
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$root",
      includeArrayIndex: "rownum"
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: [
          "$root",
          {
            rownum: "$rownum"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $facet: {
      currRow: [
        {
          $match: {
            blogCode: "B0004"
          },
          
        },
        {
          $project: {
            rownum: 1
          }
        }
      ],
      root: [
        {
          $match: {
            blogCode: {
              $exists: true
            }
          }
        },
        
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      currRow: {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          "$currRow",
          0
        ]
      },
      root: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      rownum: {
        prev: {
          $add: [
            "$currRow.rownum",
            -1
          ]
        },
        next: {
          $add: [
            "$currRow.rownum",
            1
          ]
        }
      },
      root: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$root"
  },
  {
    $facet: {
      prev: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$root.rownum",
                "$rownum.prev"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: "$root"
          }
        }
      ],
      next: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$root.rownum",
                "$rownum.next"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: "$root"
          }
        }
      ],
      
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      prev: {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          "$prev",
          0
        ]
      },
      next: {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          "$next",
          0
        ]
      },
    }
  },
]
```

**Working** [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/psY-9bCe1dX)