# MongoDB running numbers within subsets of documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a existing collection of ~12 million documents. I want to update one field in all the documents to have a running number within all groups of documents that share a common "ref" field. This would be a one time operation. Is there any way I can achieve this in MongoDB 4.4?

Simplified documents example:

```
{"_id": 1, "ref": "REF_A", "description": "aaaa"}
{"_id": 2, "ref": "REF_A", "description": "bbbb"}
{"_id": 3, "ref": "REF_A", "description": "cccc"}
{"_id": 4, "ref": "REF_B", "description": "dddd"}
{"_id": 5, "ref": "REF_B", "description": "eeee"}
...
```

Desired modified output:

```
{"_id": 1, "ref": "REF_A", "description": "aaaa1"}
{"_id": 2, "ref": "REF_A", "description": "bbbb2"}
{"_id": 3, "ref": "REF_A", "description": "cccc3"}
{"_id": 4, "ref": "REF_B", "description": "dddd1"} <- reset count because ref changed
{"_id": 5, "ref": "REF_B", "description": "eeee2"}
...
```

The running number is concatenated to description field here. As soon as the "ref" changes, the concat number counter should reset and start from 1 again. When sorted by "_id" all the same refs are already together. Order matters.

I've been looking at aggregations to solve this, but it seems I would need a way to refer to previous documents and could not figure it out yet.

The best I could find is this thread:
[Add some kind of row number to a mongodb aggregate command / pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35174554/add-some-kind-of-row-number-to-a-mongodb-aggregate-command-pipeline)
But does not seem to suit my case where row number is being reset under a condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query1

- sort by ref and descript
- group by ref and collect the docs for each ref-group
- map to add the index of each member to the description
- unwind replace root, to reset the initial structure
- you need to add `$out` stage in the end of the pipeline(see your driver how to do this), to save this to a new collection, and then replace the one you have now. (we can't use group in any update method even with pipeline)
  (only way is `$out` or `$merge`, but merge will be slower)
- set also `{allowDiskUse : true}`

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70336587-m)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$sort": {"ref": 1, "description": 1}},
  {"$group": {"_id": "$ref", "docs": {"$push": "$$ROOT"}}},
  {"$set": 
    {"docs": 
      {"$map": 
        {"input": {"$range": [0, {"$size": "$docs"}]},
          "in": 
          {"$let": 
            {"vars": {"doc": {"$arrayElemAt": ["$docs", "$$this"]}},
              "in": 
              {"$mergeObjects": 
                ["$$doc",
                  {"description": 
                    {"$concat": 
                      ["$$doc.description",
                        {"$toString": {"$add": ["$$this", 1]}}]}}]}}}}}}},
  {"$unwind": "$docs"},
  {"$replaceRoot": {"newRoot": "$docs"}}])
```

*In MongoDB 5 we have `$setWindowFields` for those, but you have MongoDB 4.4, so we only have `$group` i think, give it a try, but you have many documents.

Query2

- requires >= MongoDB 5 which you don't have now
- again you need out `$out`

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70336587-1-m)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$setWindowFields": 
    {"partitionBy": "$ref",
      "sortBy": {"description": 1},
      "output": {"rank": {"$rank": {}}}}},
  {"$set": 
    {"description": {"$concat": ["$description", {"$toString": "$rank"}]},
      "rank": "$$REMOVE"}}])
```

Comment: Query #1 solved my issue. It might be too heavy for some use cases but with 12.5M documents amounting to ~7GB, it finished in ~10 minutes without error. Fast enough for our case. Thank you!